# How do Iookup values in a pandas dataframe using rows of another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` that looks like this:

```
    field1
0   ALBER
2   LRRC1
3   JATOF
```

I also have a `df2`

```
    0     1   2
0   0     3   0
1   1   711 908
2   2   319 290
3   3   974 546
4   4   213  55
```

where each number in fields 1 and 2 stands for a value in `df1`'s index. How do I map the numbers of `df2` to the corresponding value of `df1`?

Like

```
    0         1       2
0   0     ALBER   JATOF
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df3=df2.merge(df1, left_on="1", right_index=True).merge(df1, left_on="2", right_index=True, suffixes=("_1", "_2")).drop(["1", "2"], axis=1).rename(columns={"field1_1": "1", "field1_2": "2"})
```

For the sample data I used:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame({"field1": ["abc", "xyz", "pqr", "ghi", "yyy"]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"0": [1,2,3,4,5], "1":[0, 4 ,2,2,3], "2": [4,3,3,2,1]})

df3=df2.merge(df1, left_on="1", right_index=True).merge(df1, left_on="2", right_index=True, suffixes=("_1", "_2")).drop(["1", "2"], axis=1).rename(columns={"field1_1": "1", "field1_2": "2"})

print(df3)
```

Output:

```py
0    1    2
0  1  abc  yyy
1  2  yyy  ghi
2  3  pqr  ghi
3  4  pqr  pqr
4  5  ghi  xyz

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `iloc` with `apply` and `map`:

```
df2.iloc[:, 1:] = df2.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: x.map(df1['field1']))

   0      1      2
0  0  JATOF  ALBER
1  1    NaN    NaN
2  2    NaN    NaN
3  3    NaN    NaN
4  4    NaN    NaN
```

*note*: we get `NaN` since there are no index numbers for `711, 908` etc, but this should be fine in your original dataframe.